# How does a bit field work with character types?

Tags: c++, c, char, bit-manipulation

```
   struct stats
   {
       char top         : 1; 
       char bottom      : 1;
       char side        : 2;
   } MyStat;
```

I have seen this format with integers but how does the above char bit field work and what does it represent?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Char bit fields work in the same way as int, just the base type is 8-bit wide, not 32-bit. So you'd get a struct stats, which has the size of 1 byte, and 3 member variables, occupying a total of 4 bits.

Comment: @Tommy: you should really be careful with `char` here because this is not portable and they have the ambiguity that they may be signed or unsigned types. If you may, avoid this and use `unsigned` or `_Bool`. Two bits of an `unsigned` need exactly as much space as two bits of a `char` ;-)

Comment: Not to mention you should avoid bitfields to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Bitfields should be declared with type `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or `bool` from `<stdbool.h>`. Other types may or may not be legal (depending on the platform), but be careful about the signedness — plain `int` may be taken to be unsigned for a bitfield.

That said, it may be a hint to the compiler that the alignment of the `struct` should be 1 and not `sizeof(int)`. And the compiler is allowed to accept `char` and assign it such meaning.

According to C99 6.7.2.1/9,

> A bit-field is interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits. If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type _Bool, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored.

and a footnote:

> As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is `int` or a typedef-name defined as `int`, then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.

Comment: C99 explicitly says in 6.7.2.1/4 "_Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type". Presumably the implementation is free to define whether the bit-field container object is really as small as a single `char` as it appears it could be in this case.

Comment: @RBerteig: Did I say something to contradict that?

Comment: Sorry, I apparently read "Other types may or may not be legal..." as not really saying "implementation defined". (My only excuse is immersion in standardese with insufficient caffeine.) I can't find any clear answer from the standard about what `sizeof()` should say in this case, however.

Comment: @RBerteig: I (think I) clarified it a bit. I'm pretty sure `sizeof` is implementation-defined when there's a bitfield, and I seem to recall doing an experiment with GCC where the size of the declared type did make a difference.

Comment: the embedded systems cross compilers I've used generally have taken the declared type holding the bit fields as an indication of what kind of memory access to do. So a bitfield in a `char` would use byte-acess, a `short` would use 16-bit accesses, and a `long` would use 32-bit accesses. This matters a great deal in some architectures where a 16-bit wide device may not be legally accessed 8 bits at a time without doing two reads which could loose some information in registers that are cleared when read. That is **very** implementation defined, and non-portable, though.

Answer (score 2):

it just defines the size of the variable that you will use.

```
char
int
```

This is not supported by the standard (typical use is unsigned int), but it's a nice attempt :)

re: your query, it's an attempt by the implementer to use less memory for their bitfields (char as opposed to unsigned int)

Additionally, from [Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/avr_3_04.pdf), we get:

> in the C Standard, only “unsigned
>   (int)” and “int” are acceptable
>   datatypes for a bitfield member. Some
>   compilers allow “unsigned char”
>   ........

Comment: what are the possible values for a 1 bit char?

Comment: it's not a one bit char, it's one bit inside of a char

Comment: char is one byte in size, so it takes values -128 to 127 (signed) or 0 to 255 (unsigned).  If you want to use it as a bit field, you need to use masks and the bitwise operators | & ^ ~ << and >>

Comment: @Tristan - not really. Most compilers (regardless of what the Standard says) allow bit operations like the OP details on a char.  These operations CAN use the bitwise operators but don't HAVE to use them.  For example, bitfields are a great way to define which pieces of data are sent in a stream, in which case you would turn them on and off as appropriate

Comment: from C++ (2003 version) standard: It is
implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) char, short, int or
long bit-field is signed or unsigned. >>>> I think it's reasonable to think char is supported

Comment: @buratinas - unfortunately, the OP refers to C and C++.  The good news is we're both right ;)

Comment: C99 explicitly says in 6.7.2.1/4 "_Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type". So it is allowed, but it is implementation defined and so not as portable. Of course, not a lot about bit-fields is portable.

Comment: They're portable for the use I defined earlier, but always a great danger when dealing with machine dependent stuff.  Of course, anything machine independent is 'great danger', which is why it's fun.