# Bitfields. Why is there no output?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bit-fields

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct bitfield
{
    unsigned char a : 3, b : 3;
};

int main()
{
    bitfield bf;
    bf.a = 7;
    cout << bf.a;   
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using VC++ with its latest compiler. When i type cast bf.a to int it gives the desired output (7). But when i dont type cast it, it gives no output and gives no errors. Why is it so?

Comment: simply print the integer value of a as being invisible character: `cout << (int)bf.a; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i type cast bf.a to int it gives the desired output (7). But when
>   i dont type cast it, it gives no output and gives no errors. Why is it
>   so?

The character (number 7) was written to the console. Character 7 is the [bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

---

So you can't see it, but you can hear it. Or rather I could hear the notification sound on Windows 10 when I ran the program.

The same output is generated with:

```
cout << '\a';
```

---

The bell is part of a group of characters that can be referenced with [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

---

Note that in this case the use of a `char` bitfield is not guaranteed by the standard. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3971085/1460794) for a question regarding the use of `char` bitfields.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the character who's value is 7. Others have pointed out that this is a special character that is usually not displayed. Cast your value to `int` or another non-char integer type to display the value, rather than the character. Go look at [the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and you'll see character 7 is BEL (bell).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct bitfield
{
    unsigned char a : 3, b : 3;
};

int main()
{
    bitfield bf;
    bf.a = 7;
    cout << (int)bf.a; // Added (int) here
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 1: Since `bf.a` is only 3 bits, it cannot be set to any displayable character values. If you increase it's size, you can display characters. Setting it to 46 gives the period character.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct bitfield
{
    unsigned char a : 6, b : 2;
};

int main()
{
    bitfield bf;
    bf.a = 46;
    cout << bf.a;   
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41474349/7359094) about using bitfields and `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Char type bitfield is not supported.

Bitfield declaration supports only 4 identifiers,

- unsigned int
- signed int
- int
- bool

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field)